# yolo v5 export to torchscript: how to generate constants.pkl

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

i cloned yolo5 and

- setted up an virtenv
- pip install -r requirements.txt
- `python export.py --weights yolov5s-seg.pt --include torchscript --img 640 --device cpu`

all went fine: `TorchScript: export success ✅ 1.6s, saved as yolov5s-seg.torchscript`

But if i use this Model, i get

`panic: libtorch API Error: PytorchStreamReader failed locating file constants.pkl: file not found`

The archive `yolov5s-seg.pt` contains no `constants.pkl`.

How can i generate `constants.pkl`?